# android Up button press in title bar not getting detected

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I've tried following methods for detecting back press in an activity:

```
private static final String TAG = "PRESSED";

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i(TAG,"BACK");
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Back pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Back pressed 1");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The onKeyDown, onKeyUp and onBackPressed WORK on pressing back button on "On screen buttons" at bottom of screen, which is this:
[image]

But DO NOT WORK WHEN pressing the Up button in title bar, which is this:
[image]

Why don't they work when Up button in title bar is pressed?

Comment: Try debug to check if they are called or not, or check other log level

Comment: Tried other log levels, not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?
It makes ActionBar back button work like the back button.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code in your main activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigateUp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // for closing activity 

        boolean canback = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==1;

        if (canback) {
            finish();
        }
        else {

            super.onBackPressed();

        }

    }
```

Comment: So what changes should I do?

Comment: u dont have to remove super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);